# Is there a way to download a GitHub repo and initialize it though JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github

How can I download a git repo and initialize it using JavaScript?

Comment: Do you mean `code` as in via software? Or code as in Microsoft VSCode?

Comment: What does _"Initialize it onto my Visual Studio while running"_ mean?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I mean I am looking for JavaScript code that can download a repo and initialize it.

Comment: @KingCh1ll why don't you want to use npm? npm is literally the package manager for JavaScript. Your only other option is re-writing your own git implementation.

Comment: @KingCh1ll I read your question. However 'not through NPM' was vague. I thought you meant not using NPM at all (even to install the library that fetches repositories).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clone a git repo though JavaScript:

1. `npm install nodegit` for the nodegit library - https://www.nodegit.org/
2. Clone the repo (this downloads the files and version control info). See the [node git docs](https://www.nodegit.org/guides/cloning/) for a full example

```
async function cloneRepo(){
  const cloneURL = "https://github.com/nodegit/test";
  const localPath = require("path").join(__dirname, "tmp");
  const cloneOptions = {};
  const repository = await NodeGit.Clone(cloneURL, localPath, cloneOptions);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. But, this does not solve my question. First of all, I made this post poorly and should have made sure it made more sense. I am trying to install a git repro though JavaScript code.

Comment: @KingCh1ll updated my answer with some info to help you.